# php: when need to use unset() function

Tags: php

```
<?php
$str = 'Hello world!';
echo $str;
unset($str);
?>
```

Question:

When do I need to use `unset()`? For the above script, I think that is not necessary to use it. So I just wonder in what situation need to use it?

Comment: place `echo $str` after `unset`

Comment: You would use it when you need to [*unset a given variable*](http://php.net/manual/function.unset.php)

Comment: In your case, you don't need to do an `unset` - your script is anyway ending. But `unset` is required if you want to delete elements in a PHP array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i mostly use it when deleting sessions...

```
unset($_SESSION['user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an array:

```
$test = array(
   'one' => 1,
   'two' => 2,
   'three' => 3
);
```

if you don't need three anymore easily you can do `unset($test['three']);` if you don't have `unset`, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php

$str = 'Hello world!';
$myvar = 'another var';

$params = array($str,$myvar);

myunset($params);

function myunset($params){
 foreach($params as $v){
  unset($GLOBALS[$v]);
 }
}

var_dump($myvar); //NULL
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about PHP garbage collection, first we need to know that:

> PHP performs garbage collection at three primary junctures:
>
> When you tell it to
>
> When you leave a function
>
> When the script ends
>
> http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10

You can follow the link above to get more information, my suggestion is that you can use unset when processing a big resource.

Answer (score 0):

Unset function actually use for unset the value of any variable you can do this

### unset($var);

### unset($_SESSION['logout']);

### unset($row['firstname']);